# When/Where do I use nested resources?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I have 2 classes in my rails app. App, and User.
A User has Apps, which they have edit permission over.

I also want any user to be able to list ALL apps, whether or not they have permission.

That means the apps need to be accessed two ways. 
1) /Users/1/Apps  (This would be all the user's apps)
2) /Apps  (This would be all recent apps in the system)

My question is, how do i set up routing for this reasource. 
Do I list it twice in routes? One as a standalone resource, and another nested under resource?

Do i keep the flat list, and pass a querystring with user Id?

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put this in your routes

```
resources :apps

resources :users do
  resources :apps
end
```

also, for authorizations, I can recommend an awesome gem, [cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan)

Answer (score 0):

I would go for your first option, as they are 2 different uses, one is the apps editable by the user, versus all the apps.